# Get list of requested keys in NestJS/GraphQL request

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I am just fiddling around trying to understand, thus my types are not exact.

```js
@Resolver()
export class ProductsResolver {
    @Query(() => [Product])
    async products() {
        return [{
            id: 55,
            name: 'Moonshine',
            storeSupplies: {
                London: 25,
                Berlin: 0,
                Monaco: 3,
            },
        }];
    }
}
```

If I request data with query bellow

```query
{
    products{
      id,
      name,
    }
}
```

I want `async carriers()` to receive `['id', 'name']`. I want to skip getting of `storeSupplies` as it might be an expensive SQL call.

---

I am new to GraphQL, I might have missed something obvious, or even whole patterns. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option is to directly use the @Info decorator provided by NestJS, as found here: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers-map#decorators

It could look something like this:

```js
@Resolver()
export class ProductsResolver {
    @Query(() => [Product])
    async products(
    @Info() info
    ) {
        // Method 1 thanks to @pooya-haratian.
        // Update: use this method; read below article to understand why.
        let keys = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.map(item => item.name.value);
        // Method 2 by me, but I'm not sure which method is best.
        // Update: don't use this; read below article to understand why.
        let keys = info.operation.selectionSet.selections[0].selectionSet.selections.map(field => field.name.value);
        return keys;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: After reading this article on [GraphQL Server Basics: Demystifying the info Argument in GraphQL Resolvers](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a), I have learned that fieldNodes is an excerpt of the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), while operation is the AST of the *entire* query.

As for why it's safe to select the first object in the array of fieldNodes (`fieldNodes[0]`), it is because the excerpt starts at the current field, as opposed to the root of the query.

Hence, @pooya-haratian's method was correct. I simply added the elaboration and used NestJS's decorator (`@Info`).

Comment: To test which is better try some nested queries to see what gives correct list of fields back.

Comment: Added reference to the article. Hopefully it helps better clear things up.

Comment: this map only work with one level of selection set. If the schema comes with a nested selections sets possibilities it won't work

Comment: this code snipe looks like working for nest objects


const keys = [];

function getKeys(selections) {
  selections.map((item) => {
    if (keys.indexOf(item.name.value)) {
      keys.push(item.name.value);
    }

    if (item?.selectionSet) {
      getKeys(item.selectionSet.selections);
    }
  });
}

const infoKeys = (info) => {
  keys.splice(0, keys.length);
  getKeys(info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections);
  return keys;
};

export default infoKeys;

Answer (score 9):

Basically you can seperate `StoreSupplies` queries, to make sure not to get them when query on the products.
You can also get the requested keys in your resolver, then query based on them. In order to do that, you can define a parameter decorator like this:

```js
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const Info = createParamDecorator(
  (data, [root, args, ctx, info]) => info,
);
```

Then use it in your resolver like this:

```js
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  @Query(returns => UserType)
  async getMe(@CurrentUser() user: User, @Info() info): Promise<User> {
    console.log(
      info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.map(item => item.name.value),
    );
    return user;
  }
```

For example, when you run this query

```
{
  getMe{
    id
    email
    roles
  }
}
```

The `console.log` output is:

```
[ 'id', 'email', 'roles' ]
```

Comment: Why should `fieldNodes` be used instead of `operation.selectionSet.selections`? Is this the best way of doing so? I'm attempting to do the same, but only to use `projections` for mongodb's native driver to optimize requests.

Comment: @yaharga actually I'm not sure about the best way, but I guess for most cases, like the question above, we can simply use `@ResolvePropert`. I didn't notice that till now :D

Comment: I was attempting to get the keys in order to use them with the MongoDB `projection` parameter in the `find()` function. `@ResolveProperty` would be useless there, right?

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. @yaharga

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can use @Info https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#graphql-argument-decorators decorator from NestJs which is returning an `info` parameter from regular apollo resolver.

This decorator injects parsed GraphQL query as AST and allows user to create more complex resolvers.

Working with AST is not straightforward and easy because you need to handle all query types by yourself (fragments, aliases, directives and etc)
But fortunately, there are some libs on the market that make all heavy lifting under the hood.

### @jenyus-org/graphql-utils

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jenyus-org/graphql-utils

This also has pretty useful Decorators for NestJS:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jenyus-org/nestjs-graphql-utils

CODE

```
@Query(() => [PostObject])
async posts(
  @FieldMap() fieldMap: FieldMap,
) {
  console.log(fieldMap);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "posts": {
    "id": {},
    "title": {},
    "body": {},
    "author": {
      "id": {},
      "username": {},
      "firstName": {},
      "lastName": {}
    },
    "comments": {
      "id": {},
      "body": {},
      "author": {
        "id": {},
        "username": {},
        "firstName": {},
        "lastName": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### graphql-fields-list

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-fields-list

Example in NestJS:

```
{
  post { # post: [Post]
    id
    author: {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

```
import { fieldsList, fieldsMap } from 'graphql-fields-list';
import { Query, Info } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Query(() => [Post])
async post(
  @Info() info,
) {
  console.log(fieldsList(info));       // [ 'id', 'firstName', 'lastName' ]
  console.log(fieldsMap(info));        // { id: false, firstName: false, lastName: false }
  console.log(fieldsProjection(info)); // { id: 1, firstName: 1, lastName: 1 };
}
```

### Other similar libs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-parse-resolve-info

https://github.com/robrichard/graphql-fields

Answer (score 1):

After couple tries I also managed to create my own solution which doesn't require external libraries.

field-map.decorator.ts

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

const getNodeData = (node) => {
  const { selectionSet } = node || {};

  let fields = null;
  if (!!selectionSet) {
    fields = {};
    selectionSet.selections.forEach((selection) => {
      const name = selection.name.value;
      fields[name] = getNodeData(selection);
    });
  }

  return fields;
};

export const FieldMap = createParamDecorator((_, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(ctx);
  const info = gqlCtx.getInfo();

  const node = info.fieldNodes[0];
  return getNodeData(node);
});
```

example.resolver.ts

```js
@Resolver()
export class ExampleResolver {
  @Query()
  example(@FieldMap() fieldMap) {
    console.log(fieldMap);
  }
}
```

Query

```
example {
  id
  name
  description
  child1 {
    id
    name
  }
  child2 {
    id
    name
    value
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
{
  id: null,
  name: null,
  description: null,
  child1: { id: null, name: null },
  child2: { id: null, name: null, value: null }
}
```

Comment: Do not deconstruct an object that could be `null` or `undefined`. Either use `const { } = obj || {}`, or simply use assignment. Other than that, this looks good :)